# ¿Como llamo a un tag-input con un button ? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, input, angular8

tengo una duda quizas es muy simple, pero no he logrado realizarlo, estoy aprendiendo de a poco en Angular, bueno el tema es que tengo un tag-input con un ngModel el cual lo quiero mostrar al presionar un boton (+), pero no he logrado que se muestre, en estos momentos se ve por defecto, pero quiero lograr que al apretar el boton +, aparezca recien el tag-input, alguien podria guiarme o ayudarme como podria realizarlo ?, dejo el codigo de html el cual tengo el tag-input y el boton.

````
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <tag-input class="casillaInputCorreo" [(ngModel)]="items" placeholder="Ingrese un correo."
                           [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Ingrese otro correo.'"
                           [errorMessages]="errorMessages"
                           [validators]="validators"
                           [separatorKeyCodes]="[32, 188]">
                </tag-input>
                <small class="textoDeAyudaCorreo">Ingrese uno o más correos electrónicos presionando la tecla "Enter" del teclado1</small>
            </div> 
        </div> 
       
        <div class="row pb-5">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success font-weight-bold">
            +
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success font-weight-bold mr-1" (click)="enviarEmail()">
            <i class="fa ft-arrow-right fa-fw"></i> Enviar correo
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger font-weight-bold" (click)="closeModal()">
            Cerrar
        </button>
    </div> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Lo conseguí realizando una condición con NgIf que al presionar el botón me mostrase el tag input y por defecto el estado estaba en FALSE.

Comment: Me alegra que encontraras una solución al problema, sería ideal si pudieras editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿cuál es el código que añadiste? ¿dónde se añadió? etc. De ese modo la respuesta estará más completa y será de más ayuda a otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.